# Entity Framework with Informix; - How to fix You must set this property to a non-null value of type 'Double'

Tags: c#, entity-framework, informix

Here is our work environment 
Informix Server v 12.10. (recently upgraded from 11.5)
IBM Data Server Client 10.5.3.4 (recently upgraded from 9.7.4)
Entity Framework v 5
C# 4.0

We have a table which has 2 decimal columns, both defined as decimal(11,4).
In entity class. both are declared as type "decimal?" (columns are nullable type)

When updating these two columns with decimal values (ex 123.345M), one column value changing as expected but other one taking only integer value!
Strange right! same code being used to update both columns, but only one get updated!

Here is partial code sample:
Database table DDL

```
vndr_pack_net_wgt_qty DECIMAL(11,4),  
vndr_pack_gross_wgt_qty DECIMAL(11,4)
```

C#

```
public partial class Cmrcl_Invc_Line_Item  
{   
public decimal? vndr_pack_net_wgt_qty { get; set; }    
public decimal? vndr_pack_gross_wgt_qty { get; set; }  
}
```

Initializing properties:

```
var dbContext = new ProductContext();

var lineItem = dbContext.Item.FirstOrDefault(x => x.id == 5139);

lineItem.vndr_pack_net_wgt_qty = 125.337M;  
lineItem.vndr_pack_gross_wgt_qty = 126.377M;

dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

vndr_pack_net_wgt_qty saved with **125**, but vndr_pack_gross_wgt_qty saved with **126.377**.
We observed same results even with ADO.Net (not using entity framework).

But, when we tried with `double` data type in C# program, both columns updated as expected.

So, tried to change entity property type to "double". "

```
public double? vndr_pack_net_wgt_qty { get; set; }    
public decimal? vndr_pack_gross_wgt_qty { get; set; }      

var lineItem = dbContext.Cmrcl_Invc_Line_Item.FirstOrDefault(x => x.cmrcl_invc_id == 5139);
```

after changing one property to double, i am getting exception

> **The 'vndr_pack_net_wgt_qty' property on 'Cmrcl_Invc_Line_Item' could not be set to a 'Decimal' value.You must set this property to a
>   non-null value of type 'Double'.**

Before upgrade and migration, everything was working as expected.
We are not seeing these issues on another server (production) which runs on Informix 11.5.
We are not sure what went wrong or what causing the problem.

Comment: @Adriano, in SQL it is decimal(11,4) and in C# decimal.

Comment: That comment does not help. Please include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please also read [How do I ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Thank you! Updated code samples, hope this helps.

Comment: What about using `decimal?`? Have you tried that

Comment: @Mafii, When i use decimal, one column value changed, but other column value not changed.

Comment: Do you mean these two values: `lineItem.ea_net_first_cost_amt = 124.334M;  
lineItem.vndr_pack_net_wgt_qty = 125.337D;`

Comment: @Mafii, updated question description with few more details. these values lineItem.vndr_pack_net_wgt_qty = 125.337M; lineItem.vndr_pack_gross_wgt_qty = 126.377M; net_wgt_qty not updated, but gross_wgt_qty updated. After changing to double, entity retrieval itself throwing exception

Answer (score 1):

When Informix server version upgraded to 12.10 FC7, issue got resolved.